# iPhone Facebook SDK 3 get user details & profile pic in one request

Tags: ios, facebook, facebook-ios-sdk

I'm using the Facebook SDK for iPhone. I need to be able to retrieve the authenticated users details AND profile picture in one request.

In the beta's of the SDK I used to be able to do this using the following code below, but it is now only returning the user id and the picture url.

```
[FBRequestConnection startWithGraphPath:@"me" parameters:[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:@"picture" forKey:@"fields"] HTTPMethod:@"GET" completionHandler:^(FBRequestConnection *connection, id result, NSError *error)...
```

Is there a way to do this in one request? Many thanks for any advice.

[EDIT] I should also probably mention that I require the URL string to the image directly as I am not using Facebook's new FBProfilePictureView class.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Brain fart! I should have included all the properties I wanted returned in the parameters dictionary. I was under the impression from Facebook's doc that you only had to include the picture property if you wanted it returned WITH the user information. The correct request is as below:

```
[FBRequestConnection startWithGraphPath:@"me"
                         parameters:[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:@"picture,id,birthday,email,first_name,last_name,gender,username" forKey:@"fields"]
                         HTTPMethod:@"GET"
                  completionHandler:^(FBRequestConnection *connection, id result, NSError *error) {

                  }];
```

Comment: not getting user's first name and last name using it.

Comment: Hi Bullet Raja. This question/answer is nearly two years old, Facebook may have changed their API during this time.

Comment: Hi bennythemink i just added first_name,last_name in parameter and it works.

Comment: Great thanks Bullet Raja, I've updated my answer to reflect this

Answer (score 0):

Here is an updated solution.

```
var basicUserData = ["fields": "picture,id,birthday,email,first_name,last_name,gender"]

FBRequestConnection.startWithGraphPath("/me",
    parameters: basicUserData,
    HTTPMethod: "GET") {
        (connection:FBRequestConnection!, result, error) -> Void in
            if error != nil {
                print(error!)
            } else {
                print(result!)
            }
        }
```

The Parse team recommended getting FB profile picture by accessing the https://graph.facebook.com/(facebookId)/picture?type=large  Make sure to replace  with the user's Facebook Id. [Here is the discussion](https://www.parse.com/questions/how-do-i-get-a-facebook-or-twitter-users-profile-picture)

Notes:

- **username** field is deprecated after FacebookSDK v2
- **"/me"** is the correct endpoint not **"me"**
- [This gist shows many other interactions with the Facebook Graph](https://gist.github.com/ekoneil/3178821)